# how to detect profile lang for the user that access my app tab in a page?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

how to find out profile lang for the user that accesses my app tab in a page?
I had an app, write in php and provide a app tab.
The tab was added to my page and is running...

now, for user accessing the tab, I want to know it locale... how can this be done via the php sdk?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this :

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'xxx',
      'secret' => 'xxx',
      'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$locale = $signed_request['user']['locale'];
$country = $signed_request['user']['country'];

echo "locale =".$locale;
```

Untested but might help you :)